# indexing document to a specific collection using spring data solr

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data, spring-annotations, spring-data-solr

I am trying to index a document to a specific collection in solr. The collection name is 'program'. I am using spring data solr.

I am getting the below error when trying to save the document:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /solr/update. 
Reason:Not Found
```

My assumption is that the annotation @SolrDocument is not recognized. spring-data-solr is trying to post the document to /solr/update whereas it should try to post it to /solr/program/update.However I am not sure how to prove it or fix it.

My schema is available on the link below:

```
http://<solr-host>/solr/program/schema
```

The update request handler is available in the link below:

```
http://<solr-host>/solr/program/update
```

spring-config-xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.oostnet.controllers, com.oostnet.models, com.oostnet.services" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<solr:solr-server id="solrServer" url="http://<solr-host>/solr" />

<bean id="solrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="solrServer" />
</bean>

<solr:repositories base-package="com.oostnet.solr.repositories" />
```

Model definition:

```
package com.oostnet.models.documents;

@SolrDocument(solrCoreName="program")
public class Program {

    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String id;
    <more variables>
}
```

Repository definition:

```
package com.oostnet.solr.repositories;

public interface ProgramRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Program, String> {

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.oostnet.controllers;

public class ProgramController{
    private ProgramRepository programRepository;
    @Autowired
    public void setProgramRepository(ProgramRepository programRepository) {
        this.programRepository = programRepository;
    }
    public void createProgram(Program program) {
        programRepository.save(program);
    }
}
```

Below are the versions used:

```
<spring.data.solr.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring.data.solr.version>
<spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
solr server version - solr-spec 4.10.2
```

Comment: are you able to access the `program` core admin page?

Comment: @sidgate yes. There are no exceptions there. I access it using the url http://<solr-host>/solr/#/program

Comment: which version of spring-data-solr you are using??

Comment: @Swaraj The version is available in my post. Its 1.3.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

To work on multiple collection you need to enable multiple repository under spring configuration as below :-

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.solr" />

<solr:solr-server id="solrServer" url="http://localhost:8983/solr" />

<bean id="solrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="solrServerFactory" />
</bean>

<solr:repositories base-package="com.test.solr.repositories" multicore-support="true" />
<bean id="solrServerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.MulticoreSolrServerFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="solrServer" />
    <constructor-arg name="cores">
        <list>
            <value>program</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: How do you specify the core name then?

Comment: on the pojo add @SolrDocument(solrCoreName="program"). this will take program collection url from factory.