# solrTemplate is null when referenced from custom repository using spring data solr

Tags: java, solrj, spring-data-solr

Trying to implement a custom solr repository and injected solrTemplate (using @Resource) to the custom*Impl.java but it is null and throwing below exception.

Tried all the options but in vain.

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [collection-search] in context with path [/collection-search] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/select. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your code where you try to inject the repository and not only the HTML-Output of the Error

Comment: Hi @bish, please find below code: Configuration
EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = { "package_name" }, multicoreSupport = true)
PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SearchContext {

 Resource
 private Environment environment;
 
 private MulticoreSolrServerFactory factory;
 private SolrServer solrServer;
 private SolrTemplate solrTemplate;
 
 Bean
 public SolrServer solrServer() {
   solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(environment.getRequiredProperty(SOLR_HOST));
   return solrServer;
 }

Comment: Bean
 public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {
  solrTemplate = new SolrTemplate(factory.getSolrServer());
  return solrTemplate;
 }
 
 Bean
 public MulticoreSolrServerFactory solrServerFactoryBean() {
  factory = new MulticoreSolrServerFactory(solrServer, "collection-search");
  return factory;
 }
 
}

Comment: Also created CustomDocumentRepository.java (interface that extends SolrCRUDRepository) and CustomDocumentRepositoryImpl.java that implements CustomDocumentRepository

Comment: Followed same steps as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859181/spring-data-solr-multiple-cores-and-repository/20857352

Comment: Code base is similar to following git link, https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-data-solr-examples

Comment: Similar issues is discussed in following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353201/indexing-document-to-a-specific-collection-using-spring-data-solr

Comment: Please do not post this all in the comments where it's unformated but in your question. You can edit it via the edit-button.

Comment: @bish Appreciate your interest, able to solve the issue. For some reason solrTemplate is not recognizing solrCore, so I have manually invoked setSolrCore("collection-search") on solrTemplate after injection in my custom repository class. It's working now.

Comment: Did you creat that core? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791107/solr-throwing-rg-apache-solr-client-solrj-impl-httpsolrserverremotesolrexceptio